# Is it possible to read python function output from text file with groovy script?

Tags: python, groovy, soapui

I have situation where I need to update my token every 12 hours. I have python script below which done this for me and saves it to new file. I was wondering is it possible to run this python script with groovy and after that read the value from the file and save it to variable for future use?

```
pw = WarehouseApi.from_credentials('username','password',29)
fh = open('C:\\Users\\SebastianAiraksinen\\Testi\\token.txt', 'w')
fh.write(str(pw._session.cookies))
fh.close()
```

Comment: Question for clarification: Are you running something that is continually running i SoapUI, that makes it necessary to call the python script from in there? Or is it merely out of convenience, that if the token has expired, you would like to update it automatically. I'm thinking maybe it would make sense to execute your SoapUI project from the commandline - like from a .bat file - and then as a part of that bat-file, you could call the python script just before starting the SoapUI project...?

Comment: ...I'm thinking then you could possibly take the necessary values from the python script, and pass it into the SoapUI project as input parameters at launch.

Comment: Hi Steen, Im running some REST API tests via jenkins, mainly night  runs, but i need to pass my token to header because im using JWT token and thats only way i got it to work in SoapUI. So i figure this "solution" that i generate token in python script --> Saved it to file and after that reading the token with groovy ( Not sure how to do it atm ) and then im going to save it in to variable and pass that to header --> So if im correct after that i have automate my token update

Answer (score 0):

In your comments, you state that this is running in Jenkins. So, automated. Both Python script and SoapUI execution is happening from commandline...? (Like from inside a .BAT file or something like that)

I think you may be able to make a .BAT file yourself, that runs both the Python Script AND your SoapUI project right after each other.

The Python script should return the token.

Your .BAT file should catch that in a variable.

Pass that variable to the execution of your SoapUI project.

Assuming the execution of your SoapUI project looks something like this:

```
testrunner.bat your-soapui-project.xml -Ptoken=%tokenVariable%
```

The -Ptoken=%tokenVariable% part will set a Project variable inside your SoapUI project named "token", that you may use with ${#Project#token} when running. Like when setting your header values etc.

I hope that made sense. :)